# Im trying to display binary search tree in Inorder, but it only displays "No elements in the tree", Also how can i visually display the tree elements

Tags: c++, class, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//initiating a class 'node' that is used to store the data and address of an element
class Node
{
   public:
            //initialising the data members
            int information;
            //self referential data members
            Node *leftSection;
            Node *rightSection;
            
            //default constructor
            //initialises the data members when a node is created.
            Node()
            {
               information = 0;
               leftSection = NULL;
               rightSection = NULL;
            } 
                  
};

//class that implements Binary Search Tree
class BinarySearchTree
{
   public:  
            //method to insert elements into a binary tree
            void insertIntoBinaryTree( int number, Node *root )
            { 
               //checking if tree is empty 
               if(root == NULL)
               {
                  Node *root = new Node;
                  root->information = number;
                  root->leftSection =  NULL;
                  root->rightSection = NULL;
                  cout<<"Success";
               }
               else
               {     
                  //checking the left section condition
                  if(number < root->information)
                  {
                     insertIntoBinaryTree( number, root->leftSection );
                     cout<<"Success";
     
                  }
                  else if(number > root->information)
                  {
                     insertIntoBinaryTree( number, root->rightSection );
                     cout<<"Success";
                  } 
                  else
                  {
                     cout<<"\nElement Already Exists !";
                  }
               }
            }
            
            void displayBinaryTreeInOrder( Node *root )
            {
               if(root == NULL)
               {
                  cout<<"\nNo Elements in the Tree ";
                  return;
               }
               
               displayBinaryTreeInOrder(root->leftSection);
               
               cout<<root->information<<" - ";
               
               displayBinaryTreeInOrder(root->rightSection);
               
            }
};
         
        
class callAllMethods
{
   
   public:  
            
            char menu()
            {
               char choice;
      
               cout<<endl;
      
               cout<<"\n---MENU---";
               cout<<"\n1.Add an Item into Binary Search Tree";
               cout<<"\n2.Remove an Item from Binary Search Tree";
               cout<<"\n3.Remove an Item (2).";
               cout<<"\n4.Remove an Item (3)";
               cout<<"\n5.Traverse the Binary Search Tree - In Order";
               
               cout<<"\n\nEnter your Option: ";
      
               cin>>choice;
               return choice;
            }

   
            void Call()
            {   
                int value;
                BinarySearchTree user;
                Node *Key = NULL;
                char choice;
                int number;
                int numberToBeChecked;
   
                do{ 
                  
                  choice = menu();
      
                  switch(choice)
                  {
                     case '1': cout<<"\nEnter the Number To Be Inserted into the Tree ";
                               cin>>value;
                               user.insertIntoBinaryTree(value,Key);   
                               break;
                     
                     case '2':user.displayBinaryTreeInOrder(Key);  
                     break; 
                     
                     case '3': 
                     break;   
                            
                     case '4': 
                     break;
                     
                     case '5': user.displayBinaryTreeInOrder(Key);
                     break;
                 
                     default : cout<<"System Exit";
                  }
   
               }while(choice!='6');
            
            }

};

int main()
{  
   
   callAllMethods Object;
   Object.Call();

}
```

Comment: `Node *root = new Node;` - Think about what `root` is getting that new node.

Comment: The function `insertIntoBinaryTree` never puts anything into the tree. It just makes new root nodes and throws them away. The new root nodes never become *the* root node.

Comment: `class BinarySearchTree` would currently serve better as [`namespace BinarySearchTree`](https://godbolt.org/z/zrbcG1cdT), as it is currently just a collection of public stateless functions.  The entire class has no data.  It certainly doesn't hold a search tree.  Although that might be a symptom of other oversights.

Comment: `Node *root = new Node;` shadows the parameter and even if it didn't: the parameter is passed by value, not by reference, so overwriting the parameter value has no observable effects for the caller. Furthermore for C++ code you should use the keyword `nullptr` instead of the C macro `NULL`. As noted by Drew the `BinarySearchTree` class is oorly designed: Given the type names you'd expect an instance of `BinarySearchTree` to "be a tree", i.e. own the data of a single tree instead of being an object providing functionality that can be applied to different trees.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.